# Silverlight connectivity with database using ado.net

Tags: silverlight, ado.net, using, connectivity

I want to connect my sql server 2005 database using ado.net in silverlight.

I want to connect manually to my database.

Please give me examples of populating gridview in silverlight manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't support ADO.NET. You'll have to make a web service call and have your web method access the database. Check out this [article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Getting-Started-WCF-RIA-1469cbe2) for some help getting started.

Hope this helps!